# Not getting all expected events when subscribing to sequence with TestScheduler

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift, reactor

I'm trying to write an integration test for a `Reactor` in an app built with ReactorKit and Realm/RxRealm.

I'm having trouble using `TestScheduler` to simulate user actions and test the expected emitted states.

In a nutshell, my problem is this: I'm binding an action that will make my Reactor save an item to Realm, my Reactor also observes changes to this object in Realm, and I expect my Reactor to emit the new state of this item observed from Realm.

What I'm seeing is that my test does not get the emission of the newly saved object in time to assert its value, it's emitted after my test assertion runs.

There is a fair amount of code involved, but attempting to whittle it down into a self-contained example of what it all roughly looks like below:

```swift
struct MyObject {
    var counter: Int = 0
}

class MyReactor: Reactor {
    enum Action {
        case load
        case mutateState
    }

    enum Mutation {
        case setObject(MyObject)
    }

    struct State {
        var object: MyObject?
    }
    
    func mutate(action: Action) -> Observable<Mutation> {
        switch action {
        case .load:
            return service.monitorObject().map(Mutation.setObject)
        case .mutateState:
            guard var myObject = currentState.object else { return .empty() }
            myObject.counter += 1
            return service.save(myObject).andThen(.empty())
        }
    }

    func reduce(state: State, mutation: Mutation) -> Observable<State> {
        var newState = state
        switch mutation {
        case let .setObject(object):
            // Should be called twice in tests, once on load, once after mutateState action
            newState.object = object
        }
    }
}

struct Service {

    // There is always at least one default instance of `MyObject` in Realm.
    func monitorObject() -> Observable<MyObject> {
        return Observable
            .collection(from: realm.objects(MyObject.self))
            .map { $0.first! }
    }

    func save(_ object: MyObject) -> Completable {
        return Completable.create { emitter in
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(object, update: .modified)
            }
            emitter(.completed)
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}

class MyTest: QuickSpec {

    var scheduler: TestScheduler!
    var sut: MyReactor!
    var disposeBag: DisposeBag!
    var service: Service!
    var config: Realm.Configuration!

    override func spec() {
        beforeEach {
            config = Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: UUID().uuidString)
            scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
            disposeBag = DisposeBag()
            sut = MyReactor()
            service = Service(realmConfig: config)
        }

        describe("when my reactor gets a mutateState action") {
            it("should mutate state") {

                scheduler.createHotObservable([
                    .next(1, Action.load),
                    .next(2, Action.mutateState),
                ])
                .bind(to: sut.action)
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)

                let response = scheduler.start(created: 0, subscribed: 0, disposed: 1000) {
                    sut.state.map(\.object)
                }

                // Counter always equals 0
                XCTAssertTrue(response.events.last!.value.element!!.counter == 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting to happen is my Reactor's state is set for a 2nd time, before the `XCTAssertTrue` is hit. What is actually happening is the assert is hit with the initially loaded state, and then, my reactor's state is set again.

I thought my problem might be related to schedulers. Something I tried was injecting the test scheduler into my Service and doing `observeOn(testScheduler)` on my `monitorObject` function. But I'm still observing the assert get hit before the reactor's state is set for the 2nd time. I'm also not sure if a nuance of RxRealm/Realm change set notifications is the cause - not sure how to verify whether that might be the case.

Hopefully the problem and question is clear. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Without parsing though all of the code, two questions come to mind. The first is that since Realm objects themselves are observable and will fire an event upon change, why aren't you using that feature? Secondly, you're casting a live updating Realm object to an object in memory that, while is Observable, is disconnected from Realm so if something changes in the underlying data, that object won't know about it. Maybe that's the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided attempting to write an integration test was more trouble than it was worth and probably not going to result in very useful tests anyway.

Answer (score -1):

So you are trying to test to see if Realm works. I don't use Realm, but based on your description, it probably updates the object on an internal thread and then you get the emission on a subsequent cycle.

You can test it by using an XCTestExpectation. Here is documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations

Note however, that if something goes wrong in Realm and this test fails, there isn't anything you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. This felt a little odd - but what I tried was subscribing to my observable in my test, and using XCTestExpectation.fulfill() in the subscription block. Unfortunately this did not work for me.